# Python for loop on two dimensional index

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, indexing

This may be a simple task, but I am unsure of how to achieve this in Python.

I have a for loop executing on an index in Python. I have a unique value that is defined within each iteration that is cycled through the for loop.

I want to get the value of the NEXT or PREVIOUS for loop unique value. For example, I have:

```
counter = 0

for rect in rects:
    randomnumber = random.randint(1,101)
    if counter < len(rects)-1:
        if rects[counter] - rects[counter+1]
            pastrand = {get random value from PREVIOUS loop iteration}
            randsubtract = randomnumber - pastrand
```

So how do I get the random number from the previous (or next) iteration to use in the CURRENT iteration in Python? For example:

```
  randomnumber in rects[0]
  randomnumber in rects[1]
```

How do I call specific values from iterations in for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its late in the day, but this might do you..

```
counter = 0
random =[]
for rect in rects:
    randomnumber = random.randint(1,101)
    random.append(randomnumber)
    if counter < len(rects)-1:
        if rects[counter] - rects[counter+1]:
        pastrand = random[-1]
        randsubtract = randomnumber - pastrand
```

Comment: Ok I’ve definitely been staring at this way too long - it didn’t even occur that I can just index the current random number into a new index with [counter] as the iteration! Thank you. This works!

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**
Use `enumerate`. If you want the current and next, you'll need to iterate till `len(rect) - 1`. If you want the previous and current, you'll need to start iterating from 1.

```
for i, r in enumerate(rects[:-1]):
    cur = r
    next = rects[i + 1]
```

Or,

```
for i, r in enumerate(rects[1:]):
    prev = rects[-1]
    cur = r
```

---

**Option 2**
You can use `zip` to the same effect:

```
for cur, next in zip(rect, rect[1:]):
    ...
```

Comment: he would have to error handle if it goes out of bounds right?

Comment: @MikeTung The whole `If you want the current and next, you'll need to iterate till len(rect) - 1. If you want the previous and current, you'll need to start iterating from 1.` is to handle out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

As written, you can save the value from the previous loop iteration before assigning a new one.

```
for ...:
    pastrand = randomnumber
    randomnumber = ...
```

Of course you will have to assign something to `randomnumber` before the loop starts so that the assignment works the very first time through.

An alternative would be to loop over *pairs* of random numbers rather than computing one random number per loop iteration. For this you can use the `pairwise()` tool whose implementation is given in the [`itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) or e.g. in the [`more-itertools` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools). Looping over pairs of random numbers could be done like this:

```
for rand1, rand2 in pairwise(repeatfunc(random.randint, None, 1, 101)):
    ...
```

where I have used another itertool, `repeatfunc()`, to repeatedly call `randint()`. (You can do this without using `repeatfunc()` too.) At each iteration of this loop except the first, `rand1` will be equal to `rand2` from the previous iteration.

Now, you're going to want to pair each random number with a rectangle (assuming that's what is in `rects`), right? That you can do using `zip()`. Specifically, `zip(random_numbers, rects)` is an iterator over tuples of a random number and a rectangle. You could use it like so:

```
for randomnumber, rect in zip(random_numbers, rects):
    ...
```

but you're going to want to iterate over pairs, so you combine `pairwise` with that:

```
for r1, r2 in pairwise(zip(random_numbers, rects)):
    rand1, rect1 = r1
    rand2, rect2 = r2
    ...
```

Here `random_numbers` could be that thing I did earlier with `repeatfunc()`. This will associate one random number with each rectangle, and give you access to each set of two consecutive number/rectangle pairs.